# urllib.request HTTPError: Unauthorized

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm having some problem with this code.I have a Http request where I need to request some information from an API.I'm having troubles with the urllib request, I don't think I'm using the right library because the code I got it uses urllib2 put since python 3 is different I don't know which one to use.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import os
from pprint import pprint

REST_URL = "http://data.bioontology.org"
API_KEY = "MYAPIKEY"

def get_json(url):
    opener = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    opener.addheaders = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    return json.loads(opener.open(url).read())
    print(url)

# Get list of search terms
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("__file__"), 'classes_search_terms.txt')
terms_file = open(path, "r")
terms = []
for line in terms_file:
    terms.append(line)

# Do a search for every term
search_results = []
for term in terms:
    search_results.append(get_json(REST_URL + "/search?q=" + term)["collection"])

# Print the results
for result in search_results:
    pprint(result)
```

Comment: Don't know which to use? Check the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html

Comment: I'm used the right one on the documentation.The problem is that I get this "HTTPError: Unauthorized" .